# Unable to boot from virtual cdrom/iso in supermicro server

Tags: centos7, supermicro, iso

i have a supermicro server 6048r-e1cr36n. I have tried to mount the virtual cdrom/iso however everytime its going to network boot. I tried to do F11 and select the ATEN Virtual cdrom but it goes network boot.

This happens if i reorder the boot order or selecting manually. Also i made sure, the CSM support is enabled under security tab as well. I am out of options. Pls let me know how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Is the virtual cdrom actually connected? Is the iso bootable? Have you verified the integrity of the iso? Is the image only bootable with UEFI and the system configured for BIOS boot or vice versa?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yes. Its connected and iso is bootable. I want to mount centos 7.7 iso and install the OS which i presume is bootable for both UEFI and legacy modes. and system is configured for BIOS boot and vice versa

Comment: Did you click the Plug In button and get the response "VM Plug-In OK!!" ? Or did some other message appear? Or did you not click the button?

Comment: yes,.. i clicked  the plug in option.. and i got plug in .. OK !!